Time for the SD card to return to transfer mode after writing data to sectors
I'm working with an SD card on a microcontroller. After I send a sequence of commands to write data to sectors, I wait for the SD card to go into “transfer mode” before sending the next write or read command. Usually this time of transition to the "transfer mode" mode takes 3 milliseconds, sometimes it reaches 60 milliseconds and sometimes up to 200 milliseconds.
How to understand what determines that this time is different?
How can I influence this time?
Or if I can’t influence, how can I predict it?
